# Locations of rocket impacts in Tel Aviv

Tags: israel, tel-aviv

How can one find out the locations of rocket impacts in Israel, in particular Tel Aviv? I'm only aware of this [live map](https://israelpalestine.liveuamap.com) but it's unclear how the information is sourced (certain twitter accounts?) and it's certainly out of date.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a question specifically about travel.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel

Answer (score 4):

One cannot. After the war is over you may be able to get access to that information retroactively, but it is not and should not be available in real time or close to real time as to not to allow the enemy know the effectiveness of their strikes.

Comment: More likely to publicise strikes on civilian casualties than military ones.

Comment: The Iron Dome only lets through 1 to 10 rockets in 100. Gaza is ~50km from Tel Aviv. The rockets are unguided. Kinda hard to see how the enemy would benefit much from knowing that the Iron Dome missed one of their rockets.

Comment: @DanDascalescu you're making quite a few assumptions here, not all of them may be correct. Even if they are - it is still a strategically important information. You may have to find other ways to satisfy your curiosity.